# Rewrite URL for marklogic 8

Tags: url, url-rewriting, marklogic, marklogic-8

I need to redirect requests, and I try to use this rewriter:

```
<rewriter xmlns="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/rewriter">
  <match-path matches="^/(\w+\.xqy)$">
    <set-path>/subfolder/$1</set-path>
  </match-path>
  <dispatch/>
</rewriter>
```

URL: http://marklogic:9012/query.xqy

Script is placed under `/subfolder/query.xqy`

But  it gives "page not found, 404" result.

I also tried to check what path is at the end using following:

```
<match-path matches="^.*(\w+\.xqy)$">
  <set-path>$0</set-path>
  <set-query-param name="test">/smth/$1</set-query-param>
</match-path>
```

and then I print $test, and it has "/smth/$1" value, although the following

```
<set-query-param name="test">$1</set-query-param>
```

gives "script.xqy" value.

Seems like a bug in Marklogic?!

Comment: Please edit your question instead of giving such details in comment.

Comment: Can you show the URL that's the input to the rewriter?  It's not possible to interpret the behavior without the input.

Comment: I'm sorry,

URL: http://marklogic:9012/query.xqy

Script is placed under /subfolder/query.xqy

Comment: How are you deploying your rewriter? Wondering if escaping of characters at deployment might be messing something up. You could check by looking up the rewriter xml inside your modules database with QConsole or such..

Comment: grtjn, I just uploaded file using webDav and I edit it directly on system.
For example the following construction works fine:
    <match-path matches="^/(\w+\.xqy)$">
        <set-path>/subfolder/script.xqy</set-path>
    </match-path>

Only substitution with $1 doesn't work